# Deleting an entry in a SQLite database in android

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

My name is Michael, and I am writing an android application that will serve as a very basic class schedule app. So far, I have been able to write the program so that I am able to create and add new classes to the database, however I cannot seem to figure out how to remove a selected entry from the database. The button that saves the entries is defined as follows:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />
```

and the listener that it activates is:

```
private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type=null;

            switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.math:
                    type="math";
                    break;
                case R.id.cs:
                    type="cs";
                    break;
                case R.id.pe:
                    type="pe";
                    break;
                case R.id.elective:
                    type="elective";
                    break;
            }

            if (restaurantId==null) {
                helper.insert(name.getText().toString(),
                                            address.getText().toString(), type,
                                            notes.getText().toString());
            }
            else {
                helper.update(restaurantId, name.getText().toString(),
                                            address.getText().toString(), type,
                                            notes.getText().toString());
            }

            finish();
        }
    };
```

Where the 'insert()' method is the function in my helper class that adds the entry.

The specific problem is that I am having trouble writing the 'remove()' function in the helper class. I have tried using the getWritableDatabase.delete() function, however I am having trouble finding the right parameters. Any point in the right direction would be a big help to me. Thank you in advance.

If it helps at all, this is the insert() function:

```
public void insert(String name, String address,
            String type, String notes) {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put("name", name);
        cv.put("address", address);
        cv.put("type", type);
        cv.put("notes", notes);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("restaurants", "name", cv);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you interested in something like this?

```
public void deleteValue(String value)
    {
         SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

         String whereClause = "name"+"=?";
         String[]whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(value)};
          db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, whereArgs);
          db.close();
          Log.v("done","deleted  row ");
    }
```

Here the parameter value for the deleteValue() is the one on which basis we are willing to delete a row (like delete rows based on the name) so we are using it as where clause.

see the lines

```
String whereClause = "name"+"=?";
             String[]whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(value)};
```

This can be assumed as delete statement with where clause as `where name = value;`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, this deletes the entry in the database based upon the name of the class?

Comment: No @L337Man . Suppose that you are interested in deleting a restaurant with name "xyz" then you can pass the name "xyz" as parameter to this function which is in the helper class

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. Not only did you solve my problem, but you've helped me to understand the solution. I'm sorry I can't upvote you right now, due to my low reputation, however I do highly appreciate your quick and accurate response.

Comment: well this i got to know from some other person in this SO. I would thank him for all this.
Any wayz accepting the answer would help me to understand that it solved your problem. 
And if you need to delete all the items in your table have a look at http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html .( It may be helpful to you)

Comment: For sure, Thank you very much. You've been a big help.